# Making table rows columns in another table

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have a table `subjects` with the following columns

```
-subject_id
-subject_name
-subject_code
```

This table has three rows of data.For instance,three subjects by name `science,arts,language`

I want the three rows of data to be used in another table as columns like

```
-examination_data_id
-class_students_id
-student_id
-<the three subjects rows go here> columns
```

I want the columns created from rows to have a cascade like effect meaning if a row is edited,the column name changes too.Can this be achieved in RDBMS?.

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I think the best place to start is by reading up on SQL. There is a tuorial on SQL joins here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @mzedeler Joins can't work here.I am looking for a container like a table.Joins would do it,but that is expensive.I am not looking for a pivot table too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked,

> If a row is edited,the column name changes too.Can this be achieved
>   in RDBMS?

I believe you are asking if changing the contents of some row in one table can have the side-effect of changing the name of a column in another table in an RDBMS. The answer is: No it can't, not directly. You could write some client code, or maybe even stored-procedure code, to do it by issuing appropriate DDL commands. But that could would be difficult to write, debug, and maintain.